# how to connect to mySQL on localhost via unix socket

Tags: php, sql, pdo, localhost

I recently moved my hosting server to another company. 
And I originally used db.inc.php to connect to the database, the config is as follows:

```
<?php
define('DB_INFO', 'mysql:DATABASELOCATION;dbname=NAMEOFTHEDATABASE');
define('DB_USER', 'ADMIN');
define('DB_PASS', 'ADMIN');
?>
```

but the new hosting server is "Localhost via UNIX socket"..

I'm not sure how this connection works..can I use the same php file to connect?

Comment: UNIX sockets can only be on the local machine, so "Localhost via UNIX socket" is a redundant statement.

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily found in the documentation:

```
mysql:dbname=testdb;unix_socket=/path/to/socket
```

You musn't specify host when using socket.